# Mutex to read-only variable

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

The Language is C and my app has multiple threads. I have an int array that its values can be changed and i have mutex to read and write its values. But since the base address of the array (like &arr[0]) never changes, do i need a mutex to read thiss value (base address of array)?

On main thread i have

```
int arr[10];
```

On the ohter threads i have

```
int *ptr = &arr[0]; // this line
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
*ptr = 2;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
ptr++;  // and this line
```

Do i need a mutex to do this?

Comment: Show more realistic code please.

Comment: Is `arr` a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

The question is, the *ptr is protected by the mutex or not.
As the code, the mutex is not related with the memory operation. The other thread just lock the mutex then do a write. If another thread want to write the memory, as same as this thread, it still does work.
Please do a function for the memory operation, with mutex checking, then the mutex is reasonable. Otherwise, just remove this, no use.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mutex does not harm. If both the `ptr` and the data pointed by it does not change once threads are started (i.e. only `main` sets the `ptr` and the data inside before starting any threads, and no thread writes into `ptr` or the pointed-to memory zone), you may avoid having a mutex.

If one of the thread is writing the pointer (or into the pointed to data) while other threads are reading it you do want a mutex to serialize the access (even if it may happen to work on your hardware without any mutex).

You should read a good [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

You may consider using [read-write locks](http://www.cognitus.net/html/howto/pthreadSemiFAQ_10.html) with [pthread_rwlock_rdlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html) and friends (they are often more expensive than mutexes).